# 1С альтернатива

Tags: 1с, erp

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался, слышал. Существуют ли в природе, в идеях, забытых разработках, альтернативы платформе 1С. В первую очередь с точки зрения программиста - то есть мощный конструктор хранилищ данных и форм, плюс отчеты.

Интересна любая информация, то есть скажем, старое опен-сорс, которое возможно довести до ума пойдет не менее чем промышленное и тиражное. САП - не предлагать))

Comment: Буквально вчера задавали мне похожий вопрос. Может [iFin](http://ualinux.com/ru/replace-1c) подойжет?

Comment: Может [Ананас](http://ananas.su/ananas.lrn.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:Designer) ?

Comment: Вот блин, прочитал название и зашёл предложить SAP. :)

Comment: Как я понимаю, можете еще [ананас](http://ananas.su/) посмотреть:
Помнится, лет 10 назад я на нем даже что-то пробовал. Как сейчас обстоят дела - не знаю, но, судя по сайту, он скорее мертв, чем жив.

Comment: Раз SAP не предлагать, предложу Axapta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вспомнился ["Дебет Плюс"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81) на базе Eclipse RCP и JS-скриптов.

Answer (score 5):

Существует еще [решение от мелкомягких](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dynamics/).

---

Ничего конкретного про эту штуку сказать не могу, к сожалению. Просто когда я проходил практику на одном довольно-таки крупном предприятии, там работала специально нанятая команда разработчиков, которая занималась внедрением MS Dynamics (тогда она еще называлась Axapta). Знаю только что в ней используется специальный язык на подобии с++, называющийся X++.

Answer (score 4):

Мы в свое время перебрали достаточно вариантов. Нужно был решение для торг сети, в несколько десятков магазинов и 1С ну ни как не подходила.

В результате используем такую [альтернативу 1С](http://digica.bz) и конфу для Торговли. 
Это платформа на Оракле, легко расширяется, если хорошо знаете PL/SQL и html - то уже можете писать свои модули и конфигурации. Свяжитесь с разработчиками, может они помогут с тех. консультацией.

Из того, что еще есть, посмотрите Парус, ВысшийСорт:Предприятие из местных разработок. 
MS Dynamics хвалят, из известных контор Камаз вроде перешли с 1С на динамикс, но там уже совсем неприличные деньги :)

Comment: Спасибо! Интересная штучка.

К динамиксу мы ещё пока не готовы... Я чесно пытался на нем что-то делать... Но это очень своеобразная вешь.

Comment: КАМАЗ ранее пользовал BAAN, теперь стратегия SAP и 1С. О Dinamix речи никогда не шло. Любопытный факт - когда Соллерсу продали завод малолитражек с уже внедренным бааном, баан был безжалостно выброшен и заменен САПом, хотя Баан был в то время корпоративным стандартом Соллерса

Answer (score 0):

Читал про [Ultima ERP](http://www.ultimabusinessware.com/why-devs/). Откровенно говоря странные ребята, но стек технологий классный.

Answer (score 0):

Есть аналог 1с это XAF от DevExpress, там тоже можно быстро создать приложение.https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/demos.xml

Answer (score 0):

Начнём со старенького [топика](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/971339) на LOR, возможно будет интересно проследить судьбу решений.

Далее, два [обзора](http://freeanalogs.ru/1C) бесплатных [альтернатив](http://infostart.ru/public/153840/).

Из [этого](http://daily.rbc.ru/ins/business/01/06/2015/556b160e9a794722c5540c99) следует, что сами 1С считают основным конкурентом немецкий SAP.

А вообще, что считать конкурентом - зависит от масштаба, ведь многие бизнесы сами пишут решения автоматизации под свои задачи на всём, вплоть до Common Lisp, что для специфичных кейсов всяко удобнее чем встроеные средства разработки 1С, унылость (не *убогость*, пусть, но *унылось*) которых воспета неоднократно. С другой стороны, большая часть русского рынка автоматизации бизнесов, особенно в торговле, по разным причинам ( обсуждение которых выходит за рамки топика), монопольно занята этой компанией и прямых конкурентов, увы, не имеет.